# Why the RISC instruction sets usually do not contain register to register copy instruction?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, instruction-set, risc

I had this question on my exam and i am confused because as far as i know that

```
move $t0, $a0               # COPY $A0 TO $T0
```

in MIPS instruction provides that and MIPS is a RISC processor. Am I missing something?

Comment: If they have zero register like MIPS (and most RISC-like do), then `add`/`or` are "obvious" substitutions. Without zero register it would made me scratch my head for some time.

Comment: Also it's maybe not obvious why, if you missed that part about how machine code is encoded. On RISC machines usually every instruction has size of exactly one machine "word" (32 bits quite often). So the fewer instructions you need to encode, the more bits are left for registers specification and/or immediate values. Notice that 32 bit instruction can't contain both instruction opcode and 32 bit immediate, so that's why loading full 32b constant on 32b RISC CPU into register usually takes either 2-3 normal instruction, or the constant is fetched from memory. No `move` = more bits for others.

Comment: [almost all RISC ISAs have a zero register](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52438497/995714) to remove the need for a move instruction. [Why MIPS uses R0 as "zero" when you could just XOR two registers to produce 0?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/293830/27052), [Difference between adding 0 and moving a register in MIPS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42315308/995714), [How does a zero register improve performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24646101/995714), [Why the %r0 of SPARC or MIPS, is always 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19130790/995714)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between adding 0 and moving a register in MIPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42315308/difference-between-adding-0-and-moving-a-register-in-mips)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Move` is a pseudo-instruction, and when assembled will really be a different instruction.

For instance

`move $t0, $zero` gets implemented as `addu $t0, $zero, $zero`

Comment: Ok, and do u know the answer for the initial question?

Comment: that is the answer - there is no move - it is really add

Comment: A more involved answer would be - since move can be trivially implemented as "dest=source+zero", the creators of MIPS decided not to waste a precious opcode on a dedicated move command.